# What is the name of this airfoil?

Tags: airfoil

Is there a general name for this type of airfoil? I'm having trouble finding any information on it so if anyone knows anything about it please let me know!

[image]

Comment: As the caption says: It is a reflex airfoil.

Answer (score 4):

That's a [reflexed trailing edge airfoil](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Schlag-Profil). Its center of pressure moves forward with decreasing [AOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_attack) giving it an almost constant pitching moment. It is often used for flying wings.